# CentOS how to configure autoban after failed SSH logon attempts

Tags: centos, sshd

I'm managing a virtual machine that some predecessor has set up. If I try to logon and enter the wrong password three times in a row my current IP gets banned for a lengthy time (some 30 minutes at least). I'm trying to change this behavior but I've got no clue whatsoever where to even begin. Fail2ban is installed but it's not running. pam_tally2 exists but is not mentioned in "/etc/pam.d/sshd". How can I find out which tool performs the blacklisting in order to configure it?

Version is "CentOS release 5.9 (Final)"

Comment: I would look into the iptables rules [saved by the default facilities](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-iptables.html#s1-iptables-saving). The other admin probably generated a bunch of rules and saved them as described.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Fail2ban on my server and its working for ssh. 
Follow [this link](http://www.markinthedark.nl/news/ubuntu-linux-unix/70-configure-fail2ban-for-asterisk-centos-5.html). The solution is for asterisk but you just need to modify jail.conf all other steps are same. Change maxretry = 3.